# How to create a custom Compare attribute with client-side validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

The title says it all, but I'll add a bit of background here.

Until recently, I've been using MVC's already-written `CompareAttribute` to compare two values, in this case a password and its confirmation. It's worked well, except this attribute does not display the display name, set by the `[Display(Name = "Name")]` attribute of the property being compared.

Here are the two properties being compared:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
public string New { get; set; }

[Compare("New")]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

The validation message reads as follows:

```
'Confirm Password' and 'New' do not match.
```

This works, but it's obviously not as good as it should be. The `New` should read as `New Password`, as specified by the `Display` attribute.

I have gotten this working, although not completely. The following implementation (for some reason) fixes the issue of not getting the specified name of the property, but I'm not sure why:

```
public class CompareWithDisplayNameAttribute : CompareAttribute
{
    public CompareWithDisplayNameAttribute(string otherProperty)
        : base(otherProperty)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, even though this works, client-side validation does not work. I've received an answer in another question that suggests using something like this

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CompareWithDisplayName), typeof(CompareAttributeAdapter))
```

in my `Global.asax`, however the `CompareAttributeAdapter` doesn't actually exist.

So here I am. I've got the `Display` attribute being used properly by my custom `CompareWithDisplayName` attribute, but client-side validation missing altogether.

How can I make client-side validation work with this solution in the cleanest way possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your custom compare attribute to work with clientside validation you will need to implement `IClientValidatable`.  This has `GetValidationRules` which is where you can do any custom validation you might wish.

**Example**

```
public class CompareWithDisplayNameAttribute : CompareAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public CompareWithDisplayNameAttribute(string otherProperty)
        : base(otherProperty)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
        ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        // Custom validation goes here.
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule();
    }
}
```